# How to use void* in c#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I am using API written in C++ in my C# code
I have no idea how to use void*

Here's what it looks like on the C++ side:

```
void WINAPI MyGetNoteInfoCallback(WORD p_wCountID, WORD p_wCount,
WORD p_wIndex, BYTE p_bySlot, const tGRGCA10OcrSegSnFileInfo_Pboc& p_sNoteInfo, 
void* p_pUser)
{
    return;
}
```

...

```
vSetNoteInfoCallback(m_hHandle,MyGetNoteInfoCallback,this);
```

How I can use 'this' in c#?

Comment: void* in C# is IntPtr.

Comment: @oleh But note that you can probably pass `IntPtr.Zero`: the *this* you are passing will be passed as the last parameter to the callaback method, but you don't need it in .NET, because the callback can be an instance method, so have the *this* implicitly.

Comment: The api was designed to be reasonably usable from a C++ program, allowing the client programmer to use an instance method for the callback.  Not a concern in C#.  Don't pass *this* in the vSetNoteInfoCallback() call.  Ensure its 3rd argument is declared as IntPtr and not object, pass IntPtr.Zero.  The second argument must be a variable of a delegate type, it must be declared *static* so the delegate object cannot be garbage-collected.  You don't need the p_pUser argument in the callback, declare it IntPtr.

Comment: Thanks, everyone